# Seaborn violin plot - compare all to one

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a plot like the one below produced by the Seaborn docs: https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html

[image]

Lets not mind the actual data and labels here, its just for demonstration.
What I would like to do is create all the orange distributions from the same data (as a baseline).

So all the blue distributions would be plotted against the same orange distribution for every weekday in this case.

Is this possible with the built in functionalities in Seaborn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything "built-in" to do what you want, but it's fairly easy to do if you don't mind being a bit creative with your dataframe, but you'd have to provide the structure of your dataframe to make sure.

Here's a (very inefficient) way to do it with the `tips` dataset from seaborn

```
target_var = 'total_bill'
hue_var = 'smoker'
hue_value = 'Yes'
cat_var = 'day'
grouped_value = 'ALL WEEK'

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
tips2 = tips.loc[tips[hue_var]==hue_value]
for cat in tips[cat_var].unique():
    temp = tips.loc[:,[target_var]]
    temp[cat_var] = cat
    temp[hue_var] = grouped_value
    tips2 = tips2.append(temp, ignore_index=True, sort=False)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(10,4))
sns.violinplot(x=cat_var, y=target_var, hue=hue_var, hue_order=['Yes','No'], 
               order=['Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
               data=tips, palette="muted", split=True, ax=ax1)
sns.violinplot(x=cat_var, y=target_var, hue=hue_var, hue_order=[hue_value,grouped_value], 
               order=['Thur','Fri','Sat','Sun'],
               data=tips2, palette="muted", split=True, ax=ax2)
```

[image]